# Fuzzy match with Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

This is my code so far:

```
for element in address1:
    z = re.match("^\d+$", element)

    if z:
        get_best_fuzzy("1 DEEPALI", address1)
```

In the above code, I am trying to get the matching addresses in the text file. I would like to get the exact match for house number with approximate match with residual say 80%. But, the above code is not giving me any output nor any error.

Below is the sample for my addresses:

```
002 TOWER NO. 7 UNIWORLD GARDEN SEC. 47 SOWA ROAD GURGAON Haryana 122001 India
002 TOWER NO. 7 UNIWORLD GARDEN SECTOR-47 SONA ROAD GURGAON Haryana 122001 India
09;SHIVALIK BUNGLAOW; ANANDNAGAR CROSS ROAD; NEAR MADHUR HALL;SATELLITE; 
AHMEDABAD Gujarat 380015 India
1 DEEPALI; PITAMPURA DELHI Delhi 110034 India
10; BRIGHTON TOWERS; CROSS ROAD NO.2; LOKHANDWALA COMPLEX; ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI Maharashtra 400053 India
100 Vaishali; Pitampura Delhi Delhi 110034 India
100 Vaishali; Pitampura; DELHI Delhi 110034 India
```

Please be explanatory as I am new to this.

Comment: The newer [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) has a fuzzy mechanism.

Comment: Thankyou, I have treid the below without any success :                                                                                             regex.fullmatch(r"(?:cats|cat){e<=1}", "cat").fuzzy_counts
(0, 0, 1)

Comment: The tag `fuzzy` that you used, bears the description "Do not use". Please do not use tags that have "Do not use" in their description. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even after removing fuzzy_counts, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`^`: asserts position at the start of a line

`\d`: matches a digit

`+`: matches between one to unlimited times

`$`: asserts position at the end of a line

So your regex string `^\d+$` would only match `1` or `100`, etc exactly, with no additional characters after it.

To get exact match on the house number, try `^\d+` instead

```
>>> import re
>>> element = "1 DEEPALI"
>>> z = re.match('^\d+', element)
>>> z
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
>>> z.group(0)
'1'
>>> if z:
...     print('A match is found!')
... 
A match is found!
```

You can test your regex out using online regex generators like this : https://regex101.com/

I'm not sure what your function `get_best_fuzzy` does. The error could be arising from there.

Comment: import re
for element in address1:
    z = re.match("^\d+", element)
    if z:
        get_best_fuzzy("100 Vaishali  Pitampura", address1)                                                                                                               Now when I am running the above code, it is not giving any output and getting stuck. Can I get help on this code or any alternate method for doing this?

Comment: import re
for element in address1:                                                                                                                           z = re.match("^\d+", element)
    if z:
        print(get_best_fuzzy("100 Vaishali  Pitampura", address1))

Comment: The above code is also not giving me the output instead output is:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000E440370>

Comment: Is get_best_fuzzy a function defined by you? What does it do? I can't find it in the re api documentation