# How to apply regex to get the exact house number with approximate residual address match

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy

```
import re

list =[]

for element in address1:

    z = re.match("^\d+", element)

    if z:

        list.append(z.string)

get_best_fuzzy("SATYAGRAH;OPP. RAJ SUYA BUNGLOW", list)
```

I have tried the above code, it is giving me the approximate address match for the addresses in my text file. How can I get  the exact house number match with approximate rest address match. My addresses are in format:
1004; Jay Shiva Tower; Near Azad Society; Ambawadi Ahmedabad Gujarat 380015 India

1004; Jayshiva Tower; Near Azad Society; Ambawadi Ahmedabad Gujarat 380015 India

101 GAMBS TOWER; FOUR BUNGLOWS;OPPOSITE GOOD SHEPHERD CHURCH ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI Maharashtra 400053 India

101/32-B; SHREE GANESH COMPLEX VEER SAVARKAR BLOCK; SHAKARPUR; EASE DEL HI DELHI Delhi 110092 India

Comment: You can use this`^([\d\w\-]+)(.*)$`

Comment: I am sorry I am new to regex, May I know what (\d+) does as I am getting the same result after changing this.

Comment: check here https://regex101.com/r/FCSzu5/1.

Comment: Where is the difference to [your other question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744278/fuzzy-match-with-regular-expression)? Except that this question is neither properly formatted nor have you commented on the other answer given.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understood this regex now.. However, I am afraid as it is giving me the same output as before. I want to get the exact house number with fuzzy match for remaining address. I want to find out who all people are living in the same house and so will assume they are relatives.

Comment: I am sorry, but the code is little different. I tried to comment there however, it went as a new question. My apologies, kindly bear me as I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: z = re.match("^([\d\w\-]+)(.*)$", element)       is giving me different house numbers with approximate address. I want same house number. I need help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

**Code :**

```
import re

address = ["1004; Jayshiva Tower; Near Azad Society; Ambawadi Ahmedabad Gujarat 380015 India",
"101 GAMBS TOWER; FOUR BUNGLOWS;OPPOSITE GOOD SHEPHERD CHURCH ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI Maharashtra 400053 India",
"101/32-B; SHREE GANESH COMPLEX VEER SAVARKAR BLOCK; SHAKARPUR; EASE DEL HI DELHI Delhi 110092 India"]

for i in address:
    z = re.match("^([^ ;]+)", i)
    print(z.group())
```

**Output :**

```
1004                                                                                                                    
101                                                                                                                     
101/32-B
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The output shown is for different house number, I want exactly the same house numbers.

Comment: this is exactly the same house number , you can verify it by comparing the strings mentioned above. Actually I am using the string list  put all the address in it. Then iterate each address(mentioned in list address) in for-loop to apply the regex in all input strings.

Comment: I am trying this code. Is there something I need to add to this code, as the same code is not running on my side.

Comment: whats the error you are getting while running this code ?

Comment: I am not getting any error but it is stuck from hours.

Comment: I got the result now, thank you so much. So, I have now all the groups for the house numbers. How about when I want some specific address or house number?

Comment: Also, It is not giving the complete address. It is breaking at the point where new digit is coming in that address.

Comment: I got it now, Thanks a lot.

Comment: However, I need one more help. It is printing no match where the house number is 1 digit like -                                                                                                                                1 DEEPALI; PITAMPURA DELHI Delhi 110034 India

Comment: I run the code  & its working fine for 1 digit house number as well.

Comment: just change the address list like

Comment: address = ["1004; Jayshiva Tower; Near Azad Society; Ambawadi Ahmedabad Gujarat 380015 India",
"101 GAMBS TOWER; FOUR BUNGLOWS;OPPOSITE GOOD SHEPHERD CHURCH ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI Maharashtra 400053 India",
"101/32-B; SHREE GANESH COMPLEX VEER SAVARKAR BLOCK; SHAKARPUR; EASE DEL HI DELHI Delhi 110092 India",
"1 DEEPALI; PITAMPURA DELHI Delhi 110034 India"]

Comment: Thank you for your help again. But that is not solving my issue for segregating same addresses together. It is just grouping house numbers together.

Comment: cleaned = []
list =[]
Dict = {}
for element in address1:
    cleaned.append(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', element))
for element in cleaned:
    M = get_best_fuzzy(element, cleaned)
    if len(M) > 0:
         Dict[element] = M
    
for element in Dict:
     z = re.match("^([^ ;]+)", element)
         if z:
            list.append(z.string)
            print (z.group())

Comment: I am first segregating all the approximate addresses and then trying to get all same address with same house numbers out of that filtered values.